# x86 cmp Opcode, Pointers and Inline Literals

Tags: assembly, x86, cmp

I am using gdb to examine a program. In assembly, the code is doing:

```
cmp $0x5, %eax
```

However, when I examine the contents of `%eax`, I get: `\020\343\377\377\377\177` when examined as a string.

How is `\020\343\377\377\377\177` compared to $0x5 in assembly?

Comment: What do you mean "the contents of %eax"?  Examined as a string?  A register can't hold any meaningful string in the C sense.

Comment: That's a pretty wide eax you got there.

Comment: Examined it by calling something like: x/30s $eax

Comment: OK, so you dereferenced `%eax` as a pointer to get that data.  That has nothing to do with `cmp`.  Writing answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp`, in this case, is comparing the value in `eax` to a constant `5`.  The value pointed to by `eax`, if you think it is in fact a pointer, isn't compared to the constant at all.

The comparison is done by subtraction - in your case, that means `5` is subtracted from the value in `eax`, and several flags (CF, OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF, according to the [documentation](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc36.htm)) are set appropriately.  Normally the `cmp` instruction is followed by a conditional instruction of some kind (often a jump), to perform different actions depending on the results of the comparison.

If you tell us the value in `eax`, rather than interpreting `eax` as a pointer, I might be able to give you some more information.  You can use `p $eax` or `info registers` to get the value of `eax` in gdb.

Comment: When running p `$eax`, I get: 6307568. I am sorry but what is the difference between `x/30s $eax`and `p $eax`?

Comment: `p $eax` shows the value in `eax`.  `x/30s $eax` uses `eax` as a pointer, dereferences it, and shows the results as a string.  Check the gdb documentation for `x` vs `p`.

Comment: Just for people's future reference, here's the `gdb apropos` for them both: `x -- Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS`, `p -- Print value of expression EXP`